# Wi-fi internet speed for terminal is slow, internet speed on web browser is fast

Tags: networking

I just installed a fresh install of 32-bit 12.04 LTS Pangolin today. When I tried to install a few applications, it was really slow. But when I download a .deb or .tar.gz file from on my web browser, it is a lot faster.

Computer specs:

HP Pavilion Slimline s7700n PC

[Memory]         873.7 MiB

[Processor]      AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Provessor 3800+ x 2

[Graphics]       GeForce 6105 LE/integrated/SSE2/3DNOW!

[Disk Size] 638.5 GB

I normally get 200-400 kbps.

This is the comparison.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2HPd.png

Comment: You mean using apt-get?

Answer (score 6):

Probably the download mirror you're using is slow. Try this:

- Open Software Center > Edit > Software Sources
- Under "Ubuntu Software" tab click on others in "Download from" menu

[image]

- In next dialog box click on "Select Best Server".

[image]

- It will search for best server for you, Once done click on "Choose Server" That's it!

**Additional Sources:**

[Official Archive Mirrors for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Comment: It works... Thanks..... I experienced the slow Internet connection in terminal which annoyed me. After changed the Server, it is fast. Thanks for the info...