# Slow internet speed only on terminal - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, networking, internet

I am getting very slow internet speed in the terminal. Whenever I try to install any software/package with `apt-get install` or do `apt-get update`, the internet speed is very slow, like about 20 kB/s (160 kb/s) while my internet speed is 10 Mbps. I have an ASUS FX-553VD-DM483 laptop, and I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu and several Linux distributions multiple booted. Screenshots are attached.

The speed on the terminal:
[image: The speed on the terminal]

Actual Speed on browser:
[image: Actual speed on browser]

I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139187/wi-fi-internet-speed-for-terminal-is-slow-internet-speed-on-web-browser-is-fast) of the same problem but it suggests to change the server to the best server. I have a personal computer on the same network which gives more than 1 MBPS speed on every terminal operation from the same Indian servers. So the problem lies in my laptop Ubuntu itself. I thought of drivers issue but if it was a drivers issue then browsers might have given slow speed, but browsers giving considerable amount of speed and all other applications like Tixati and torrent. Please help!

Note: I tried with both Wifi and Wired with my laptop; same problems occurs with both.
**Note:: I have installed kali repositories and some of the kali tools using the tool katoolin from github!**
I tried finding the best server and still the speed is same.

Comment: What happens when you change the server?

Comment: You're installing from ftp.yzu.edu.tw, which appears to be a Kali Linux mirror. I get speeds of about 16kB/s from this site. Try a different mirror. Anyway, this is a kali mirror, and has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: One of the servers in your terminal screenshot is Taiwanese. Are you sure there isn't a closer one?

Comment: Edit: I updated to Ubuntu 18.04, and before I installed kali linux tools from katoolin, so it selected that kali linux server resulting into slow speed. Now I get full soeed in my terminal as well as browser.